# Passing parameter to jenkins job from java code

Tags: jenkins

I have create a parameterized jenkins job. But instead of taking parameters from user I want to pass it from java code. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a remote access API https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API You can also check the reference at the bottom right of each page

Comment: I also want the build status of the job but the Rest service returns status code 200 while the job is still running. How can i get the build status back from Rest service?